# Как настроить wss соединение?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, express

```
const express = require('express');
const config = require('config');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

app.ws('*', function(ws, req) {
  ws.send('q')
});

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

const key = fs.readFileSync('ssl/private.key');
const cert = fs.readFileSync('ssl/certificate.crt');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('ssl/ca_bundle.crt');

const options = {
  key: key,
  cert: cert,
  ca: ca
}

const https = require('https');

https.createServer(options, app).listen(443)
app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.secure) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
  }
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  })
}

const PORT = config.get('port') || 5000;

async function start() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(config.get('mongoURI'), {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true
    });
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`App has been started on port ${PORT}...`));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Server Error', e.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

start();
```

Клиент: `const ws = new WebSocket("ws://example.ru")`
(вырвал куски кода, что бы не выкладывать тут полотно, вроде бы все нужное для моего вопроса взял)
Суть: в юзер скрипте на чужом сайте хочу подключить соединение через веб сокеты.
Приведенный код работает для http, но браузер ругается на миксед контент и поэтому приходится подключаться на клиенте через wss, но в таком случае сервер возвращает ошибку: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200.
Я так понимаю это именно потому, что у меня ws подключение на сервере через https, но я не сильно что то понимаю в ноде и поэтому прошу помощи.
Как мне настроить правильно всс соединение?

Answer (score 0):

Не правильно

```
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);
```

Правильно

```
const https     = require('https')
const fs        = require('fs')
const express   = require('express')
const expressWs = require('express-ws')

const serverOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
  ...
}

const app       = express()
const server    = https.createServer(serverOptions, app)

expressWs(app, server)

app.ws('/echo', (ws, req) => {
    ws.on('message', msg => {
        ws.send(msg)
    })

    ws.on('close', () => {
        console.log('WebSocket was closed')
    })
})

server.listen(443)
```

Обратите внимание 1:

```
expressWs(app, server)
```

Обратите внимание 2:

В репе последний коммит в 2018 году, в issues [This project seems to be dead #135](https://github.com/HenningM/express-ws/issues/135) и множество жалоб на неработоспособность в связке с новыми версиями [express](/questions/tagged/express). Я бы такой пакет не использовал.

Обратите внимание 3:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws